# Facebook SDK link share is removing referral url

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, share

When I share link with referrer, Facebook SDK (v4.8) will remove it from link.

For example I have following link:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mypackage.myapp&referrer=utm_source%3Dfacebook`

The actual post on wall contains link without referrer:

`http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mypackage.myapp`

Code:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mypackage.myapp&referrer=utm_source%3Dfacebook"))
        .build();

        shareDialog.show(content);
}
```

Comment: What is the `og:url` meta tag value, or the canonical URL set for your referral URL? Facebook takes the `og:url` resp. canonical as the “real” URL of any Open Graph object. // Facebook append some tracking parameters themselves, maybe you can get the data/reporting you need from that already? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#ref

Comment: From Open Graph object debugger, the og:url is "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mypackage.myapp"

Comment: So fb_ref is tracking "which site bring user to FB" right? Because I need to track which site (link) bring user to play.google.com.

Comment: No, I don’t think you get that kind of information from those tracking parameters. Probably the easiest solution would be if you set up different URLs with different tracking parameters, and have those redirect human visitors to the app store URL. (Downside of that would be, that likes/shares will be counted for each of those URLs individually.)

Comment: This was reported as a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1457909784525707/) previously. However, we marked it as "Won't Fix" for the time being based on our investigation. You could subscribe that report and add more info if needed there.